# ESP 32 : Sending data over WIFI

Tags: wifi, esp32

I want to connect a Lidar sensor to my ESP 32 and send the results to my laptop over WiFi. The sensor can take readings approximately at a rate of 1,500/sec so I am looking to send a reading consisting of a distance in cm and an angle ( eg 40123,180.1).
I would like to send the data as near to real time as possible. I have successfully tried sending data using both websockets and server sent events but I cannot get anywhere near the speed needed to send single readings, the asyncServer gives an error message saying that too many messages are queued.

So the my question: Is there another protocol that I can use on the ESP 32 which will achieve this? If so could anyone give me a simple example to test.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you encode your distance and angle values as an integer (4B) and float (4B) then your payload data would be in the neighbourhood of 8 * 1500 = 12KBps which is not too demanding. The bottleneck, I suspect, would be the number of packets per second that the ESP and your WiFi equipment+environment can handle. I wouldn't be surprised if 1500 packets per second is too much to ask of it. Batch your readings into as few packets as your latency requirements allow and then send. E.g. batching 50 samples into a single packet would mean sending 30 packets per second, carrying 400 B of payload each. The latency for the oldest sample in your packet would then be roughly 33 ms + network latency (which add another 1-1000 ms depending on how busy your ether is).

As for the protocol, UDP is usually used for low-latency, low-jitter stuff. Mind you, it doesn't handle packet loss in any way - once a packet is lost, it's lost. Also, packets might arrive out of order. If you don't like that, use TCP which recovers from packet loss and orders them. The price of TCP is significant added latency and jitter as the protocol slowly discovers and re-transmits lost packets, delaying the reception of newer data on receiver side.

As for an example, google for "posix udp socket tutorial".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking of batching and that would  be perfectly acceptable to get the job done but I was searching for other solutions. I will lookat your suggestion and get back. Alan

Comment: Since your bandwidth requirement is reasonably low, you can probably get the job done with any application protocol that's not profusely verbose. The trick is to convince it to batch data in the underlying TCP or UDP datagrams. I find it more reliable to skip the middle man in such case and use the transport protocol directly.